# How to determine if there are even numbers in a string

Tags: c#

Hi I have a problem that I almost solved. Here is my problem:
Let's write a console application that prints all the numbers in a series of whole numbers.
The numbers are entered one per line, and the application will read one by one until the user writes the character instead of a number. When the user has typed x, the application knows that all the numbers in the string have been entered and displays one by one all the numbers that appear in the string in the order they were entered.

If the numbers are not in the string, the application will display the N / A text.

Example:

For input:

4
3
6
7
X
The console will display:

4
6

This is my solution for problem:

```
            string[] numbers = new string[10];
        for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            numbers[i] = Console.ReadLine();
            if(numbers[i] == "x")
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            if (Int32.Parse(numbers[i]) % 2 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
            }
        }
```

And I don't have a clue how to do the last part of this problem, the one who 
requests me to display the N / A text. Please help!

Comment: Maybe instead of displaying the output in the last loop, add them to a list in the last loop.  Then check if the list is empty.  If it is, display "N/A".  Otherwise, loop over the list and display its contents.

Comment: You say "numbers are entered one per line", but show them entered all on one line. You say "the character" without saying what character first. You later say "user has typed x" but your sample input shows "X". You say "display the N / A text" without saying what "the N / A text" is. Your title says "if there are even numbers" but your post has nothing about even numbers in it. You say "If the numbers are not in the string" which makes no sense.

Comment: Why the downvotes tho? i don't see a problem with this question.

Comment: lol took me a few reads to understand the 2 loops. ok but be sure to see if that X is not in the array tho, cause you doing a parse and it will break :)

Comment: also to output that N / A you could just have a bool variable set to true only when your conditional is true, that way you know if you found any numbers after the loop ends.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've used Google Translate and it didn't do the job well. In addition of my code, I only need to display the text 'N/A' if there are no even numbers in the string and I don't know how to do that.

Comment: well you have some options as answer, take a look :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took your code and made a few changes in it.

1. check if you reading X from the array before you parse
2. added a bool variable so you know when you found a number
3. check if the bool variable is false, so you can print N/A

   ```
   string[] numbers = new string[10];
   bool found = false;
   for(int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
   {
       numbers[i] = Console.ReadLine();
       if(numbers[i] == "x")
       {
           break;
       }
   }
   for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
   {
       if(numbers[i] != "x")
       {
           if (Int32.Parse(numbers[i]) % 2 == 0)
           {
               found = true;
               Console.WriteLine(numbers[i]);
           }
       }
   }
   if(found == false)
   {
        Console.WriteLine("N/A");
   }
   Console.ReadLine(); //So you can pause and see the output.
   ```

Kept the code as simple as possible so you can really see whats going on.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this would be to store your numbers in a `List<int>` instead. Then, when reading input from the console, you can use `int.TryParse` to determine if the input was a valid integer. If it is, and if it's even, add it to the list; if it isn't we can exit the loop.

Then we can check the list count to determine if any even numbers were entered, where we will either display them if count > 0 or we output "N/A".

For example:

```
var evenNumbers = new List<int>();

// Infinite loop is exited by the 'break' command below
while (true)
{
    // If the user enters a valid integer, TryParse will store it in this
    int number;

    // We read a line from the console and pass it to int.TryParse, which will
    // return 'true' if the input is a valid int and will store it in 'number'
    // If it returns false, then we break from the loop
    if (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number)) break;

    // If the number entered is Even, add it to our list
    if (number % 2 == 0) evenNumbers.Add(number);
}

// If there are any items in our list, then print them. Otherwise print "N/A"
if (evenNumbers.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (int evenNumber in evenNumbers)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(evenNumber);
    }
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("N/A");
}
```